# Empty Interface Usage in Pipe-Filter Design Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm creating a tool which does a lot of processing on the input fed into the tool and produces output.
Here is how i have designed the Tool.
I use Pipe-Filter Design Pattern.
 I have classes named Engines that does a Job.
Output of first Engine is the Input to the second Engine.
Or it is possible that output of first and second is the Input to the third Engine.

Below is the piece of code that is present in PrincipalEngine.cs(entry point of the Tool from which other Engines are executed):

```
var contentReadEngineOutput = ExecuteEngine(ContentReadEngine, EngineInput);
var contentParserEngineOutput = ExecuteEngine(ContentParserEngine, contentReadEngineOutput);
var ruleReadEngineOutput = ExecuteEngine(RuleReadEngine, null);
var ruleRunnerEngineOutput = ExecuteEngine(RuleRunnerEngine, contentParserEngineOutput, ruleReadEngineOutput);
ExecuteEngine(ResultPublishEngine, ruleRunnerEngineOutput, contentReadEngineOutput);


private IEngineEntity ExecuteEngine(ILinterEngine engine, params IEngineEntity[] engineEntities)
{
    if (engineEntities != null)
        engine.InitializeEngine(engineEntities);        
    return engine.RunEngine();
}
```

All engines including PrincipalEngine implements the interface ILinterEngine:

```
public interface ILinterEngine
{
    void InitializeEngine(params IEngineEntity[] engineInput);
    IEngineEntity RunEngine();        
}
```

Engines are DI injected into PrincipalEngine and ran by providing inputs so as to get the output.
All Engines have an EngineInput type and an EngineOutput type.

For example, below are the engine input/output for Principal Engine:

```
public interface IPrincipalEngineInput : IEngineInput
{
    System.Collections.Generic.List<string> UrlList { get; set; }
}

public interface IPrincipalEngineOutput : IEngineOutput
{
    List<RuleViolatingNodeWithURLModel> RuleViolatingNodeWithUrlModelList { 
get; set; }
}
```

And IEngineInput and IEngineOutput implement IEngineEntity.

```
public interface IEngineInput : IEngineEntity
{

}

public interface IEngineOutput : IEngineEntity
{

}

public interface IEngineEntity
{

}
```

**Now here is my Question:**
As evident from the above code, IEngineInput and IEngineOutput has base interface as IEngineEntity.
But this interface is empty and has been used so that output of one Engine can be passed as input to the Next Engine in the 'ExecuteEngine' method.
Is this approach correct or is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Yes.  You need to change from : ExecuteEngine(ResultPublishEngine, ruleRunnerEngineOutput, contentReadEngineOutput);
to : ResultPublishEngine = ExecuteEngine(ruleRunnerEngineOutput, contentReadEngineOutput);  The two parameters to method should be the input engine and the entities.

Comment: this is not chain of responsability design pattern, it's known as pipe-and-filter architecture or simply filter architecture or even data flow  architecture.

Comment: @jdweng. Sorry i didnt get it. As per your comment, input engine should be a parameter, but in the code you suggested i see it as the result returned from the method.

Comment: @La Vloz Merrill. I think you are right. Thanks for that input. I will edit the question title.

Comment: You code isn't consistent.  The method is defined as : IEngineEntity ExecuteEngine(ILinterEngine engine, params IEngineEntity[] engineEntities).  You weren't calling the method correctly.  That is what I was pointing out.  My posted correction may not be exactly correct.

Comment: @jdweng. This is the line you are talking about right:
` ExecuteEngine(ResultPublishEngine, ruleRunnerEngineOutput, contentReadEngineOutput);` <br/>
These are the parameters to the method:<br/>
ResultPublishEngine - input Engine.
ruleRunnerEngineOutput - first entity.
contentReadEngineOutput - second entity. <br/>
I'm not sure how it is called incorrectly.

Comment: Regarding the question - I do not think than an empty interface is bad solution. It is rather a matter of taste. 

Though (I assume that you check if parameters passed match expected types) you could as well go with `object` to avoid introducing additional entities - e.g. instead of `IPrincipalEngineInput` you could use `List<string>` and so on. 

As for this case you could as well have two overloads of `Execute` in an `Engine` class. The one that accepts typed parameters and another one accepting `params object[] arguments` and basically just performs basic validation.

Comment: Why are you making ResultPublishEngine an input parameter when it is an output?

Comment: @jdweng. engine is the first parameter of the `ExecuteEngine` method. Here we pass 'ResultPublishEngine' in place of that parameter. 
I'm not sure how you say it is output.

Comment: Isn't ruleRunnerEngineOutput which is the output of the previous engine the input to the new engine?